# How can I vectorize a while loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, while-loop, vectorization

Consider the following code:

```
vectorize.me = function(history, row.idx=1, row.val=0, max=100){
  while (row.idx < max & row.val < max) {
    row.idx <- row.idx + 1
    entry <- paste('row.idx: ', row.idx, ' row.val: ', row.val)
    history[row.idx] <- entry
    print(entry)
  }
  return(history)
}

max <- 100
history <- vectorize.me(vector('list', max), max=max)
```

I'd like to do the following:

1. Instead of passing `row.idx` and `row.val` arguments, I'd like to pass a data frame to the `vectorize.me` function and have the function operate on each row idx and row val of the data frame.
2. Remove the `while` loop, and simply stop iterating when the conditions are met.
3. Return the `history` list when finished iterating.

How can I do something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(sample(0:100,1000,rep=TRUE))
history <- vectorize.me(df, vector('list', max), max=max)
```

**EDIT:** This is an entirely contrived example. I contrived it because I wanted some example code which passes values to the next "iteration" inside of vectorized code (i.e. apply, lapply, mapply, etc.)

Comment: In your code - you are not changing the row.val inside the function? Why are you using it in the condition of the while loop? For random, is there a reason why random stopping is required (not data-dependent in this case)?

Comment: If the number of iterations in the loop is random you can't vectorize it. You could implement it in Rcpp rather easily.

Comment: The fact that you want to print the random value is the main stumbling block here. Your random value causes stopping with a fixed probability of 1/100. I.e. the number of rows allowed due to random stopping follows a geometric distribution. The total number of rows is at most max. So you can sample simply from a geometric distribution, and if it is larger than max, do at most max. Then the rest is easily written in vectorized form given that you now write a fixed number of rows (but you don't have the "random" variable now explicitly).

Comment: @HolgerHoefling: This is a contrived example; in reality, row.val will be used in a calculation inside of my vectorized function, and that will be included in a condition of the while loop.

Comment: @Roland: OK. I didn't know that. What if the random part wasn't included? Could we vectorize it then?

Comment: @HolgerHoefling: OK. What if we removed the random part? That was entirely contrived.

Comment: Strategies for vectorization depend on the specific task. A contrived example is not useful here.

Comment: @Roland: My task is to pass information from one iteration to the next; except that when you vectorize, there are no iterations as such. Furthermore, my production code is extremely similar to the code above, but I can't share my production code because it's proprietary.

Comment: "My task is to pass information from one iteration to the next" That's not possible for the general case in a vectorized manner. For specific cases, there are vectorized functions like `cumsum`, `cumprod`, `cummax`, ... Please note that `*apply` functions are just hidden loops and shouldn't be considered "vectorized". They are more readable, but not faster than a well written `for` loop. A `while` loop is extremely rare in R code. If you truly need it, you usually should switch to compiled code for performance.

Comment: What @Roland says. In order to use something in vectorized manner you need full data available at the moment. E.g. `data.frame(x1 = 1:10, x2 = rnorm(10)) %>%
  mutate(x3 = if_else(x2 < 0, "", paste0(x1,"blah",round(x2,2))))
` using `dplyr`. Is this what you are aiming for ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumprod` on a series of zeroes and ones, to obtain a series that becomes 0 as soon as the first zero value is encountered in the original series. This can be used to restrict the length of `history` and the items to be printed.

Not worked out as a function but just simple code:

```
df <- data.frame(ids=seq(1,1000),val=sample(0:100,1000,rep=TRUE))
valmax<-80
pyn<-cumprod(df$val<valmax)
history<-paste("row.idx",df$ids[pyn>0],"row.val",df$val[pyn>0])
print(history)
```

You may have to add some checks and conditions to turn this into good code, but in principle this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
vectorize.me <- function(df, var, history, max=100) {
  #-- Compute the max index in df to process (this is the "stopping condition" of the "loop")
  # Find the occurrence of the first index in df[,var] that is larger than 'max'
  # (note the fictitious FALSE and TRUE values added to the condition on df[,var]
  # in order to consider boundary conditions in one go)
  indmax <- min( which( c(FALSE, !df[,var] <= max, TRUE) ) ) - 2

  if (indmax > 0) { # There is at least one index to process
    # Limit indmax to the length of 'history'
    indmax <- min(indmax, length(history))
    ind <- 1:indmax
    entries <- paste('idx:', ind, 'val:', df[ind,var])
    history[ind] <- entries
    print(entries)
  }

  return(history)
}

#-- Test
# Test data
df <- data.frame(x=c(5, 8, 9, 8, 10, 4, 1, 3))

# Run tests
history <- vector('list', 8)
history <- vectorize.me(df, "x", history, max=8)   # first 'max' value is found in a middle row
history <- vectorize.me(df, "x", history, max=4)   # first value in data frame is larger than 'max'
history <- vectorize.me(df, "x", history, max=max(df[,"x"]))      # all values in data frame are <= 'max'
history <- vectorize.me(df, "x", history, max=max(df[,"x"]) + 1)  # 'max' is larger than the maximum value in df[,var]
history <- vector('list', 6)
history <- vectorize.me(df, "x", history, max=max(df[,"x"]))      # 'history' is shorter than the maximum index of df to process
```

Notes:

- Parameter `var` specifies the name of the column in the data frame on which the condition on `max` is applied.
- No checking is done on the validity of input parameters